# How to Set Custom Fonts in size classes in xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6, size-classes

I am working on universal application.

I am using size classes for that but  I am facing some problem related to custom  fonts.

I have created custom label class and apply that to over UILabel.
Below is my MyLabel.h file.

```
MYLabel.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyLabel : UILabel

@end
```

Below is my MyLabel.m file.

```
#import "MyLabel.h"

@implementation MyLabel


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

}

-(void)awakeFromNib {

    UIFont *custom = [[UIFont alloc] init];
    custom = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-SemiboldIt" size:18];

    self.font = custom;
}

@end
```

After that I have given MyLabel class to UILabel.

[image]

And set the property according to the below picture.

[image]

Though I am not able to see change in my font.It shows same font for Ipad and Iphone.

please help me out.I am newbie in Size Classes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go through this one first: http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/. Probably an issue in setting up custom fonts. `t shows same font for Ipad and Iphone` do you want two different fonts for each devices ?

Comment: I think you can not see Custom font in right side panel. So you need to put a condition for device specific font. **Note: Assuming that custom font is loading correctly**.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. Just write below code in your `MyLabel.m` file instead
 of awakeFromNib method.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    // Implement font logic depending on screen size


        self.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:5.0f];


}
```